# Mesons sea and valence contribution

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, elementary-particles

I want some clarity regarding sea and valence quarks.

Is sea quarks and gluons contribute in the properties of mesons like masses, spin distribution etc. and how they will contribute?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Similar question for the proton: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474084/50583; is there a reason the answer would be different except for the specific numbers?

Answer (score 1):

[This is an illustration](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) of how the proton is composed :

[image: strong text]

One could have analogous ones for all hadrons.

> Is sea quarks and gluons contribute in the properties of mesons like masses, spin distribution etc. and how they will contribute?

As you see it is a many body problem, and a particular quantum mechanical model has been devised, called [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD) that can give answers to these questions.

> Lattice QCD is a well-established non-perturbative approach to solving the quantum chromodynamics (QCD) theory of quarks and gluons. It is a lattice gauge theory formulated on a grid or lattice of points in space and time.

Properties "like masses" come out of the solutions of the quantum mechanical problem, the hadrons being bound states of the total, with fixed masses. [Here is an example of such calculations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7805).

Comment: Is there any operator for masses of mesons that we can apply on valence and sea wavefunction both as well and calculate its value?

Comment: search "masses of mesons from lattice qcd " to see the complexity , QCD on the lattice is not a field theory.