# Energy stored in the gluon fields -- in a proton, versus, in a pure Yang-Mills mass gap

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, protons

I was reading this [How much of the proton's mass is due to the Higgs field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474084/42982) and finds the discussion says:

> As [Prof. Strassler explains in the link above](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-structure-of-matter/protons-and-neutrons/), the proton mass is best throught of as arising from the sum of three contributing terms:

> 1. The sum of the rest energies of all of the (many!) quarks and antiquarks

> 2. The kinetic energy of the quarks, antiquarks, and gluons

> 3. The binding energy stored in the gluon fields, which is negative and actually decreases the proton mass relative to what it would be if the quarks did not interact.

> I believe that the Higgs mechanism is responsible for the contribution (1), which is much larger than the naive 9.1 MeV from just three quarks, and therefore much more than 1% of the proton mass.

### My Question goes as

In the above, we say:

(a) The binding energy stored in the gluon fields, which is **negative and actually decreases the proton mass**.

But I thought

(b) The SU(3) Yang-Mills gauge theory has mass gap, that has to do with the glue ball and the binding energy stored in the gluon fields --- which should contribute a **positive energy and a mass gap** --- to the glueball.

Which of (a) and (b) statements are true? How could they, if both (a) and (b), are true?

Comment: The whole question is a misbegotten, hardly meaningful, fool's errand: you are trying to quantify flakey popular science terms and thinking. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/474126/66086) helps you deconstruct it. (b) is closer to some truth than (a) [*Never* talk about binding energy of a hadron!] but the sum of the masses of the current valence quarks, is, indeed, close to 9.1MeV. Nobody computes anything in this framing. One abuses standard techniques to cook up "answers" to such questions to satisfy misguided popular science misconceptions.

Comment: The answer to the linked question refers to this lattice paper https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.212001 that decomposes the hamiltonian into it's various components, it would seem a lattice calculation for the various components of glueball mass would also be possible in principle. To point out some details to your questions; you would still have some contribution of quark-antiquark mass+kinetic energy to glueball mass (its not just glue)